# ARM Inline assembly for C code not executing

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly, armcc

I am trying to use inline assembly for an ARM C code.
My 'main.c' code looks something like this:

```
...
void jump()
{
  __asm
  {
    B  0x15000
  }
}


INT32 main(void)
{
  ...
  Write val1 into register 1
  jump();
  Write val2 into register 2
  ...
}
```

When I run this code I expect that `val1` to be written in register 1, and then jump to address `0x15000` happens and there is nothing written in register 2.
But when I look at register 1 and register 2 both have been written with `val1` and `val2`.
So it seems the `jump()` does not take place.
Am I missing something?

***Update 1***

As suggested in the comments, I created a minimum reproducible example which is:

```
void jump()
  {
    __asm
    {
      B  0x15000
    }
  }

int main(void)
{  
  int i, j, k;
  i = 1;
  jump();
  j = 2;
  k = i + j;
  return 128;
}
```

when I compile it with `armcc --asm main.c` I get this as `main.s`:

```
        ARM
        REQUIRE8
        PRESERVE8

        AREA ||.text||, CODE, READONLY, ALIGN=2

jump PROC
        BX       lr
        ENDP

main PROC
        MOV      r0,#0x80
        BX       lr
        ENDP


        AREA ||.arm_vfe_header||, DATA, READONLY, NOALLOC, ALIGN=2

        DCD      0x00000000
```

so it looks like the jump() is optimized out? What is that and how can I prevent it?

***Update 2***

I even tried adding the `volatile` before the function name as:

```
 volatile void jump()
  {
    __asm
    {
      B  0x15000
    }
  }
```

but it didn't help and the `jump()` function is optimized out.

Comment: Use a debugger, step through assembly instructions. Or for starters at least look at the compiled assembly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. unfortunately I don't have access to a debugger, and am a beginner. Just looking at what I am doing do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Create an  [mcve] so we could compile it and look at the generated assemly.

Comment: Would something like this be good enough:

INT32 main(void)
{
  void jump()
  {
    __asm
    {
      B  0x15000
    }
  }
  
  int i, j;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  
  i = 1;
  jump();
  j = 2;
}

Comment: Do you have compiler optimizations turned on? i and j are maybe being set to 1 and 2 when initialized.

Comment: This syntax does not seem to be accepted by ARM GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/anhGYcnMe

Comment: @HumbertoGomes maybe compiler optimization is turned on, could that cause the jump() to be eliminated?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am using armcc.

Comment: Then just compile it yourself and post the assembly here. armcc is proprietary and not commonly available.

Comment: Have you tried using the volatile keyword with the inline assembly?
The compiler might decide to optimize the assembly away if you don't add it

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How do I do that?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with the syntax of armcc, but i would guess it goes either right in front or after the __asm,

[check the docs here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100748/0606/ddx1471430827125)

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry I had a mistake in the code, this one shall work with ARM GCC :

  void jump()
  {
    __asm
    {
      B  0x15000
    }
  }

int main(void)
{  
  int i, j, k;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  
  i = 1;
  jump();
  j = 2;
  k = i + j;
  return 128;
}

Comment: @TJ1, compiler optimization wouldn't delete the jump instruction, but it may change the order things are executed. For example, you say j = 0, jump and then say j = 2. The compiler somtimes isn't very good with assembly and think that the jump() function doesn't do anything. So, it optimizes your code like this: i = 0; j = 2; jump(); This is just a possibility and may not be the case.

Comment: GCC -O1 ignores the variables completely. If you write `return i + j` GCC transforms it into what would be `return 3`: https://godbolt.org/z/ra3TeavbW

Comment: If you don't have a debugger, that's your number 1 problem.  You should fix that.  (Even if just in a simulator, not on your real hardware).  Many problems in asm become a lot more obvious when you single-step and watch register values change.  (Although in this case, looking at the compiler's asm output may be sufficient.)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just did and posted the assembly, it looks like jump() is optimized out, what can I do?

Comment: Interesting. Which version of armcc do you use? In fact I see that the call to `jump` was optimized out as well.

Comment: I use version 5.01 of armcc.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is a great comment. Would you mind look at the asm output and tell me why the jump is optimized out and what can be done?

Comment: I don't know how ARMCC inline asm works, or whether it has any equivalent of GNU C `asm volatile` vs. just plain `asm`.  In GNU C inline, it's generally not safe to jump out of an asm statement either, but maybe ARMCC is different.

Comment: FWIW v5.01 is quite buggy. v5.06 is backwards compatible and is fixing many bugs. Also it is using same license, so better move to it..

Comment: I'm not surprised `volatile void jump()` did nothing.  If it's not already implicit for an `asm {}` block instead of GNU C style `asm("template" :outputs : inputs : clobbers)`, you'd need to apply it to the `asm` keyword, not the function containing it.  `volatile void foo()` doesn't mean "don't optimize this function".

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your help. I tried to put volatile after `__asm` as `__asm volatile` and it didn't do anything. Tried to add it before as `volatile __asm` and it gave me error. Any idea of how shall I do that?

Comment: I tried that if I put after it doesn't do anything and if I put before it gives me error.